# How to match part of postfix log with regex?

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I need to match the following part of a postfix log using grep.

`Aug 6 16:00:35 d1234567-002-e3 postfix/smtp[16032]: 3E60C7832`

```
                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

So far the only way I've been able to do it is using negative lookahead, but that's not allowed in my current implementation of grep (not using perl regex).

I assumed I could do something along the lines of... (not complete solution)

`.*:.*:.*:`

Comment: 1.  Please _please_ show what you have 2. You say you are not using Perl regex but you tagged perl ... ? While you say _have_ a Perl solution.

Comment: `grep 3E60C7832`?

Comment: What are the criterias?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ s="Aug 6 16:00:35 d1234567-002-e3 postfix/smtp[16032]: 3E60C7832"
```

For the `sed` solution,

```
$ sed -E 's/.*]: //' <<< "$s"
```

For the `grep` solution,

```
$ grep -oP ']: \K.*' <<< "$s"
```

For the `awk` solution,

```
$ awk '{print $NF}' <<< "$s"
```

Comment: Nice. (But they did say that their `grep` can't use Perl's regex.) In Perl regex there is no need for `$`

Comment: @zdim, thanks, I offered another `awk` solution to replace the `grep` solution.

Comment: Even nicer -- but I didn't mean to suggest to remove the `grep` solution!  The question _is_ tagged with Perl, and that regex shows how to use Perl for it.  I'd leave it and perhaps just comment?

Comment: Yes, that's also confused me If perl is allowed or not. I'll leave the `grep` solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following patterns

```
 my $s = "Aug 6 16:00:35 d1234567-002-e3 postfix/smtp[16032]: 3E60C7832";

 if($s=~m/.*:\s(.+)/)
 {
    print $1,"\n";
 }
```

or if you want to track by the colon you can use the following regex,

```
 if($s=~m/^[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+:\s*(.+)/)
 {
    print $1,"\n";
 }
```

In your regex you have mentioned `.*:.*:.*:` along with this need to add another `.*` so the complete regex was `.*:.*:.*:(.*)`. But this is not a good regex, Because `*` matches zero or more times with **greedy** for every search it will go to the end then it will backtrack to match the `:`.

To avoid the greedy match we can use `?` along with `*` and `+`. But for your problem negation character class (`[^:]`) is the best solution.

**Greedy match**

For this `.*:.*:.*:(.*)` pattern it will give the result after 212 steps. [check here](https://regex101.com/r/c5TRQG/5/debugger)

**Non greedy match**

With this `.*?:.*?:.*?:(.*)` pattern it will give the result after 59 steps. [check here](https://regex101.com/r/c5TRQG/3/debugger)

**Negation character class**

With this `^[^:]+:[^:]+:[^:]+:(.*)` pattern it will give the result after 11 steps. [check here](https://regex101.com/r/c5TRQG/4/debugger)

Answer (score 0):

```
my ( $mail_id ) = m{postfix/smtp[\d+]: (\w+)}
```

I mean, you did tag it perl, right?

so:

```
perl -lne 'm{postfix/smtp[\d+]: (\w+)} and print $1,"\n;' postfix.log
```